# Seaching for "number" in one cell while copying another piece of data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I am trying to do in Excel is take my first sheet, which is tracking training completed. I am placing a training topic and if they attended, by entering a "1" under their name. 
[image: First Sheet]

On the next sheet is each individual student's record. I want to search the first sheet from the individual sheet for a "1" and record the training's name on their indiviual sheet. I have used `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1",'Sheet 1'!C)),B1,"")` on the invidivdual's sheet to copy the first line over. I can't seem to grasp how to search throught he entire column and then also fill in the first blank (as the first training listed may not have been the first attended). I cannot utilize VBA either due to network security restrictions. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `=VLOOKUP()` or `=INDEX(MATCH())`?

Comment: Sorry to clarify. Students have 4-5 trainings a week. If there is training Monday-Thursday, they may only make it to Tuesday, Wednesday, etc. I have to take note of all trainings but sort them out which trainings they did attend. I am looking to fill in the first line of their individual sheet with e.g. the second training. Also Vitata, no I haven't used VLOOKUP or INDEX. I am looking into both now.